# Concatenating vectors while adding their elements - creating a valid time vector

Tags: matlab, vector, time

I have several vectors I would like to concatenate, where each element is an increasing timestamp, but how do I concatenate the vectors while ensuring to have an continuously time scale?

Say, I have two vectors `tone1_time` and `tone2_time` both given by `1x4801 double`.  Each element of the vector contain a timestamps and thus the elements must be added when the vectors are concatenated in order to have the correct time. So far I have;

```
n = 10;

for i = 1:n
    time(n,end) = tone1_time + tone2_time;
end
```

Which generates an error in matlab!

EDIT: More code

I generate two sounds vectors and concatenate them by:

```
% repeat n times
n = 10;

signal = [ tone1_signal tone2_signal ];

signal = repmat(signal,1,n);
```

This will e.g. return a new vector `signal` with a length of e.g. `1x48020 double`. The time vector needs to have the same size as this vector, but also still having an continuously time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to add the last element of `tone1_time` to all elements of `tone2_time` to ensure continuity of the time intervals:

```
tone2_time = tone2_time + tone1_time(end);
```

Then you can concat them

```
tone_time = [tone1_time, tone2_time];
```

Alternatively, you can work with the differences

```
tone_time = cumsum([diff([0 tone1_time]), diff([0 tone2_time])]);
```

**EDIT:**
For replicating the time vector:

```
tone_time_diff = [diff([0 tone1_time]), diff([0 tone2_time])];
tone_time = cumsum( repmat(tone_time_diff, 1, n) );
```

Comment: Is it possible to replicate `tone_time` n times and still maintain continuity of the time?

Comment: @MikaelKP what do you mean by that?

Comment: The two time vectors are generated when I generate two different sounds. The two sounds must be played one at a time, so first sound1, when sound 2, next sound 1 etc... So is it possible to replicate the time vectors, so it matches the replication of the sounds?

Comment: use the second solution using diff and cumsum

Comment: I still have some problems with the overall length of the new time vector. If I replicate the two time vectors ten times for example, the new time vector only have a length of `1x4802 double` instead of `1x48020 double`, which is the length of the sound vector - how do I get around this?